# Why can't I connect to my Firefox account on my Ipad?

Tags: ios

When I try to connect to my Firefox account on my (old) iPad running iOS 9.3.5 and Firefox 25.1, I get an error 'Impossible de charger la page' (Impossible to load the page).
I tried to delete the app and install it again. With no success...

Any idea?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?  Go to the hamburger menu, click on “what’s new.”

Comment: As showed by App Store (and as I said in the question), version is 25.1. "About" of "Settings" of hamburger menu says Version 8.3 (5826).